# Compare Two Directories with Files, then give the result difference in another File.. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compare

I am comparing two directories with files in them. One is an old directory(Old), and the other is a new one(New) that has more files in it. I am able to print the output showing all the added files, but it only shows one file in the Result file where I actually want it to go. How can I get it to show all the files added in the Result File?

Output on Visual Studio

[image]

Output in Result File

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    String New = @"C:\Compare\New";
    String Old = @"C:\Compare\Old";
    String Result = @"C:\Compare\Result";
    DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(New);
    DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(Old);

    // Take a look of the file system.  
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    //A custom file comparer defined below  
    FileCompare compare = new FileCompare();

    // Check if same or not.
    // bool because of FileCompare
    bool areSame = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, compare);

    if (areSame == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Directories match.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Directories do not the same.. Please Review 'Result.text'.");
    }

    // Find the set difference between the two folders.  
    // Print to the result.txt
    var difFromOld = (from file in list1
            select file).Except(list2, compare);

        foreach (var result in difFromIOld)
        {
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Result);
            file.WriteLine("The following files do not match between Directories:");
            file.WriteLine("");
            file.WriteLine(result.Name + "\n", true);
            file.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
        }
}
}


class FileCompare : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    public FileCompare() { }

    public bool Equals(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2)
    {
        return (f1.Name == f2.Name && f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileInfo fi)
    {
        string s = String.Format("{0}{1}", fi.Name, fi.Length);
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `var difFromOld = (from file in list1 select file).Except(list2, compare);` you could use `var difFromOld = list1.Except(list2, compare);`

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your button click code is that a typo?

Comment: @MethodMan: the "extra" probably is the class closing brace, where the class opening brace is not posted

Comment: @MarkusEgle.. Same result.

Comment: Yes, the bracket was from extra code on the top. Apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a new StreamWriter in every iteration through your foreach loop.
By default, the StreamWriter overwrites the files contents.

The best solution is to change your loop so it looks like

```
using(var file = new StreamWriter(Result)) {
  foreach (var result in difFromIOld)
  {
  /* Write to 'file' here */
  }
}
```

You can also specify that the StreamWriter should append to, not replace the file: `new StreamWriter(Result, append: true)`. But it's better to only open the file once.

Comment: ...and move the line `file.Close()` behind the loop

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wrapped the loop in a using, so you can just remove the `file.Close()` altogether. The file will be closed when the program leaves the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, i not proved the code you may have to adapt some things

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> DifferentFiles;
//if neww dir has more files than old dir
int j;
foreach ( var dir in list1 )
{
    j=1;
    for (int i=0; i<list2.count; i++) 
    {   
        if (!compare.Equals(dir1,list2[i])) j++
    }
    if (j==list2.count){
        //dir1 is not in list2
        DifferentFiles.Add(dir1);
    }
}
/*
//Add this code to know if there are directories in List2  that are not in list1
//ass the first for is not proving it. 
foreach ( var dir2 in list2 )
{
    j=1;
    for (int i=0; i<list1.count; i++) 
    {   
        if (!compare.Equals(dir2,list1[i])) j++
    }
    if (j==list1.count){
        //dir2 is not in list1
        if(!DifferentFiles.Contains(dir2)) DifferentFiles.Add(dir2);    
    }
}
*/

StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Result);
//if 2 for is not added
file.WriteLine("The following files in the new Directory are not in the Old one:");
//if 2 for is added
    //file.WriteLine("The following files are not in both directories");
file.WriteLine("");
foreach(var result in DifferentFiles)
{
    file.WriteLine(result.Name + "\n", true);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
}
file.Close();
```